# Why is JS:Cryptonight considered a virus?

Tags: malware, web-browser, javascript, virus

Why is JS:Cryptonight (crypto miner) considered a virus? 
It does seem like a good alternative to ads. (According to https://coinhive.com/)

[image: Sample Avast Detection]

Comment: It can uses resources of the target without their permission - This may help https://sensorstechforum.com/what-is-jscryptonight-and-how-to-remove-it/

Comment: @iainpb unless it *does* ask for permission. And that's coinhive's point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. It's not self-replicating it's not a virus.  It is, however, malware because it steals a victims' resources without their knowledge/consent.

Pretty much anyone who understands the code is going to block it with something like NoScript, while the rest of the victims who don't understand what it is or what it does will have compute power and bandwidth (which ultimately costs them real money when they have a higher electric bill or less battery life on their phone) taken from them.

Just because the code is on a website doesn't make it any less malware ... if someone wrote a bitcoin miner into winzip or the dropbox client ... people would riot (and rightfully so).

Ultimately this question is opinion based and should most likely be closed.

Comment: I think whether it's malware or not depends on how the site is using it. In theory a website could get a user's consent before using a miner script, and some of the use-cases Coinhive suggests on their site (like users allowing mining in exchange for in-game currency) seem to imply exactly that. (Though yeah, in practice many of the sites using these scripts are doing so without the user's consent, while _also_ showing ads on top of that.)

Comment: sites that don't ask ... its malware, and sites that do ask ... people will say no

Comment: Depends on what incentives the site offers. The Coinhive site suggests offering users an ad-free experience or in-game currency, for example. Some users might be fine with a site using their CPU if it means no ads.

Comment: pretty sure anyone who wants an ad-free experience that understands what coinhive is ... will just run adblock.

Comment: They don't need to understand what Coinhive is, they just need to know it lets a site use their CPU to make money, and the consent dialog will explain that. Plus there are other incentives that can't be bypassed with an adblocker which a site could offer. Access to otherwise paywalled content for example.